# Custom Angular Library hosted on Azure artifacts in accessible in Angular project

Tags: angular

I am facing issues with using a custom "angular library" which is hosted on Azure Artifacts.
This is what was done
1: A new angular project was created.
2: .npmrc file was created and added to the root of this project
3: "vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc" command was fired on terminal on VSTS (worked well)
4: npm install @test/test-portal@0.0.0 was fired
5: Package get downloaded under "node_modules"

when I try to access some component from the library, its not accessible at all.
File "public-api.ts" is in place in Angular Library Project.
This library was tested after build locally by accessing in angular project and it worked.

I am not able to understand what is missing. I have gone through many tutorials but not able to find anything which tells me, if I missed something.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get any error? Could you post it?

Comment: I eventually have found the issue. We did not fire the command "npm pack" and deployed the library on Azure artifact. So what happended, one file was missed and one extra file was there. This was the main reason. When we fire npm pack command we will have a file with name <libraryName>.d file apart from  "public-api.d" file. Now  everything works.